# PHP CodeIgniter: My code to delete database data is not working correctly, can you spot the issue?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

Basically I am trying to delete database data when a use presses a delete button, the way this works is I have the data in the table, I collect it via an array of arrays (the arrays inside the array represent each record), pass it into the view, display each record (some of it), the user decides whether to delete it, if they press delete then the field data is posted back into my controller and passed into a model where it runs a query to delete the data based on the UID it has, this should work, but what is actually happening is that everything works and I don't get any errors, but the data isn't deleting, I suspect it is because the form isn't posting the data back properly, do some of you deep CI users know why? Here is relevant code:

Controller:

```
public function clist() { //function to show the client list and edit/delete buttons
        $this->load->model('list_model');
        $fields = $this->list_model->listcliname();
        $data = array();
        $data['fields'] = $fields;
        $this->load->view('clientlist', $data);
        if ($_POST['del'] === 1) { //if the user selects the delete button then call model to delete the fields for the button they selected
        $fields = $_POST['fields'];
        $this->list_model->delcli($fields);
        }
```

Model:

```
class list_model extends CI_Model {

public function listcliname()
    {
        return $this->db->get('clients')->result_array(); //get an array of arrays (one array for each record in table)
    }
public function delcli($fields)
    {
        $this->db->where('UID', $fields['UID']);
        $this->db->delete('clients', $fields);
    }

}
```

view:

```
<html>
    <body>

            <?php
            foreach($fields as $field) {
                 ?>
                 <ul>
                 <li>
                 <?php echo $field['name']; ?>
                 </li> 
                 <li>
                 <?php echo $field['contact']; ?>
                 </li>
                 <li>
                <form action="clistedit" method="post">
                <button name="UID" type="submit" value="<?php echo $field['UID']?>">edit</button>
                <input type="hidden" name="sub" value="1" />
                </form>
                </li>
                <li>
                <form action="clist" method="post"> 
                <input type="hidden" name="fields" value="<?php $field ?>" />
                <button name="del" type="submit" value="1">delete</button>
                </form>
                </li>
                </ul>

                 <?php
            }

            ?>
```

(you can probably ignore the form with clistedit form action, that is working correctly)

any help is appreciated, thanks!

EDIT: It may be because what I am posting back is an array? I could split up the array and add multiple hidden submits to submit each value and then add them to an array again in my controller but I would like to avoid this.

Comment: where have you defined the action of the form?

Comment: <form action="clist" method="post"> 
                <input type="hidden" name="fields" value="<?php $field ?>" />
                <button name="del" type="submit" value="1">delete</button>

Comment: What is result of var_dump($_POST['del'] === 1)? If it is false then in if statement put $_POST["del"]=="1"

Comment: is $fields['UID'] array in where condition?

Comment: Okay so I did that and now I am getting the errors "Message: Illegal string offset 'UID'

Filename: models/list_model.php

Line Number: 15"

and:

"Message: Uninitialized string offset: 0

Filename: models/list_model.php

Line Number: 15"

I tried changing it back and I am still getting these errors and I am unsure what they are telling me

Comment: Yes  $this->db->where('UID', $fields['UID']);

Comment: anyone answering this please see the edit to my question and tell me if that is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically it was the fact that I was trying to post back an array! There were also a few other bugs (I will post the revised code) but I was under the impression I would need all of the data to actually delete a record but because the query is something like "DELETE FROM table WHERE UID = someint" then I actually only needed to post back the UID so I echoed the UID index from my field array and fixed the other bugs and it works!

Controller:

```
public function clist() { //function to show the client list and edit/delete buttons
        $this->load->model('list_model');
        $fields = $this->list_model->listcliname();
        $data = array();
        $data['fields'] = $fields;
        $this->load->view('clientlist', $data);
        if ($_POST['del'] == 1) { //if the user selects the delete button then call model to delete the fields for the button they selected
        $fields = $_POST['fields'];
        $this->list_model->delcli($fields);
        }
```

Model:

```
    public function delcli($fields)
    {
        $this->db->where('UID', $fields);
        $this->db->delete('clients');
    }
}
```

View:

```
<html>
    <body>

            <?php
            foreach($fields as $field) {
                 ?>
                 <ul>
                 <li>
                 <?php echo $field['name']; ?>
                 </li> 
                 <li>
                 <?php echo $field['contact']; ?>
                 </li>
                 <li>
                <form action="clistedit" method="post">
                <button name="UID" type="submit" value="<?php echo $field['UID']?>">edit</button>
                <input type="hidden" name="sub" value="1" />
                </form>
                </li>
                <li>
                <form action="clist" method="post"> 
                <input type="hidden" name="fields" value="<?php echo $field['UID']?>" />
                <button name="del" type="submit" value="1">delete</button>
                </form>
                </li>
                </ul>

                 <?php
            }

            ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed to print the value of field in following line

```
<input type="hidden" name="fields" value="<?php $field ?>" />
```

change it to

```
<input type="hidden" name="fields" value="<?php echo $field ?>" />
```

You can inspect element to check if hidden field has proper value or not.

Comment: I can't do that because $field is an array

Comment: if field is an array then you can use echo implode(',', $field);
then in model file you have to use 
 $this->db->where_in('UID', $fields['UID']);
but please pre process $fields['UID'] to prevent sql injection